# Scale 1080p screen to 720p - everything is too small

Tags: display, display-resolution

I used to work on a 720p laptop screen, and now I have a new 1080p laptop screen with the same 15.6" size. With this higher resolution, everything is too small, and my eyes get tired faster. Is it possible to scale everything to 720p but keep the resolution 1080p?

I tried using Accessibility, but that doesn't scale everything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, go in : **Parameters** > **Display** and set  “**Scale for menu and title bars**” to the value that is best suited for you.

[image: Scale for menu and title bars]

It will scale all your desktop while keeping your original 1080p resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Making reference to the image that @hg8 shared, you can also try the option "Scale all windows contents to match:". Try to set that one to "Built-in Display".